# Counting duplicates with within three column tuple

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the format shown below (Exhibit 1). The table has 38mm records in it representing Opens and Clicks for three months.  A separate report has shown that there were 11mm opens in the month of January, of which 7mm were unique. I would like to verify that this table has 7mm unique opens.  OpenFlag has a 1 if a Subscriber opened an Email, and a 0 if not. When there are multiple messages with unique MessageID’s per subscriber, I only want to count 1 (dedup).

Could anybody point me in the direction of a relatively simple query (using Count, Sum, distinct etc) that could count unique opens? I know I can use @vars to distinguish the first subscriberID/month  within a set of equal subscriberID/months but with different messageID’s and keep running counts, but I’d like to avoid that complexity in this case.

Exhibit 1:

```
create table TrackerSub
(  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Time datetime NOT NULL,
  SubscriberId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  MessageId int(11) Default NULL,
  OpenFlag int(1) default null,
  ClickFlag int(1) default null,
  Month int(2) default null,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're just testing to see that a subscribe has opened any email from the database:

```
SELECT SUM(SubOpens) FROM (
    SELECT 1 SubOpens FROM TrackerSub
    WHERE OpenFlag = 1
    GROUP BY SubscriberID
) opens
```

if you're trying to see how many unique subscribers opened each message...

```
SELECT MessageId, SUM(SubOpens) FROM (
    SELECT MessageId, 1 SubOpens FROM TrackerSub
    WHERE OpenFlag = 1
    GROUP BY MessageId, SubscriberId
) opens
GROUP BY MessageId
```

I think that accurately represents your schema (at least, how I understood it) - and helps! Good luck!

Comment: thanks Jim for your very quick response! the query gets me count of 1 for each unique message ID. Do you know how to extend it to sum all the 1's by subscriberID? i'm having a bit of trouble with the outer subquery syntax

Comment: Does each MessageID only relate to a single SubscriberID? If so, are you testing to see how many Unique MessageID's were opened by each subscriber? (PS. Sorry for the delay, didn't see that you had commented on my answer)